# Why is `{foo: function myName() {}}` acceptable syntax?

Tags: javascript, function

Is there a different outcome (scope etc...) between the following two function declarations?

```
var myObj = {
    foo: function myName() {}
}
```

---

```
var myObj = {
    foo: function() {}
}
```

Comment: See: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: the 1st option helps with debugging and recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the scope is the same. In javascript anonymous functions can be named and its good practice to do so because when debugging they are named in stack traces. Also you can refer to the function inside itself. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).

Answer (score 1):

when you give a name to the function, it's only available from inside that function

```
var myObj = {
   foo: function myName() {
        myName()
   }
}
```